How to load just one item from the data list?

I wrote it after seeing that someone else had created code for a different purpose.
I don't know the principle, But it just works.
I tried to write for dcss(game) RC
The content of the image is a list of orders that are being memorised.
The purpose of the code is to enable efficient training of memorized spells
It works normally when training 1 spell (now only have 1 memorized spell in total)
When memorizing multiple spells saved in SetSpellTraining
Start training it all
But, starting to train multiple spells "at the same time" is very inefficient.
(image situation, memorising a few orders.)
function ready()
SetSpellTraining("Passwall","Earth Magic","Earth Magic","Earth Magic",1)
SetSpellTraining("Mephitic Cloud","Conjurations","Air Magic","Alchemy",5)
SetSpellTraining("Ensorcelled Hibernation","Hexes","Ice Magic","Ice Magic",1)
SetSpellTraining("Corpse Rot","Air","Necromancy","Poison",5)
.
.
.
-- I have over 20 SetSpellTraining but I didn't write them here.
end

local school_a_cost = tonumber(you.skill_cost(school_a))
local school_b_cost = tonumber(you.skill_cost(school_b))
local school_c_cost = tonumber(you.skill_cost(school_c))
local school_2_min_cost = tonumber(math.min(school_a_cost,school_b_cost))
local school_3_min_cost = tonumber(math.min(school_a_cost,school_b_cost,school_c_cost))

if spells.memorised(spell_name) then
    if school_a == school_b then
        if spells.fail(spell_name) > fail_chance then
            you.train_skill(school_a, 1)
        else
            you.train_skill(school_a, 0)
        end
    elseif school_a ~= school_b and school_b == school_c then
        if spells.fail(spell_name) > fail_chance then
            if school_a_cost == school_2_min_cost then
                you.train_skill(school_a, 1)
                you.train_skill(school_b, 0)
            else
                you.train_skill(school_a, 0)
                you.train_skill(school_b, 1)
            end
        else
            you.train_skill(school_a, 0)
            you.train_skill(school_b, 0)
        end
    else
        if spells.fail(spell_name) > fail_chance then
            if school_a_cost == school_3_min_cost then
                you.train_skill(school_a, 1)
                you.train_skill(school_b, 0)
                you.train_skill(school_c, 0)
            elseif school_b_cost == school_3_min_cost then
                you.train_skill(school_a, 0)
                you.train_skill(school_b, 1)
                you.train_skill(school_c, 0)
            else
                you.train_skill(school_a, 0)
                you.train_skill(school_b, 0)
                you.train_skill(school_c, 1)
            end
        else
            you.train_skill(school_a, 0)
            you.train_skill(school_b, 0)
            you.train_skill(school_c, 0)
        end
    end
end

end

Q
Currently the code written in the text works, but if there are multiple memorized spells like in the image, they "start training at the same time". While training one spell, I want to stop training another spell.

you should narrow your goal for a post on stack overflow to 1 question at a time, asking multiple questions will likely get your question closed for "needing more focus", Also to improve you chances of an answer include any frameworks or libraries you are using, I am not seeing any clues to that in your post. so i have no idea what SetSpellTraining is doing

i change to title and deleted it, leaving only the one question I wanted the most.
setpeslltraining is a name, can change it to any name.
I've never learned lua
I just copied it after seeing someone else load the information like this. This is just code written in the game's init.txt file
Nothing is written other than the content of the code.

Ok so it sounds like it is your code, can you add the function to the post, so the code that defines SetSpellTraining, and is this just a game coded in lua or are you working inside roblox, minecraft, gary's mod, Love2d, or anything like that?

I am writing in notepad, Full code is in the text Please wait a moment. My question lacks information.
I'll write again in the comments

Currently the code written in the text works, but if there are multiple memorized spells like in the image, they "start training at the same time". While training one spell, I want to stop training another spell.
